# Undefined value from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it is probably a very simple problem with a simple solution, but I am new to js and jquery. I have a div in html and I created this in js:

```
$("#Data").html(`
    <div>
        A: <input type="text" id="A1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        B <input type="text" id="B2"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        C <input type="text" id="C"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit" onclick="submit1()"/>
    </div>
`);
```

Also, values of A1 and B2 are set (depending on which radio is checked and what options are chosen).
And when I am trying to get the value of C (with alert), it seems to be undefined. Why is that?

```
var C=$("#C").val();
alert("A="+A+" B2="+B2+" C="+C);
```

A1 and B2 are just fine (are they?).

Here is my finished code with all those dropdowns and radios [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3t8hqLj/1/)

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (the code in the question is not complete, the code you link to is far from minimal) **in the question itself**. Preferably [as a live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment "var C=$("#C").val();" is not in a function but at the root of your script.

It will be executed when the script is interpreted, after its loading. At this moment (page load), C has no value because your input is not still in the DOM.

You need to make this value get in your method "submit", at each submit.

The assignment is NOT a binding, so you need to update the value of C each time you want to read input value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to get the value of the inputs outside of your functions but those parts run at instantiation, not when you click the button.

So when your page loads, of course the values are undefined because you are getting the val of an empty input. You need to properly pull the values into your submit function. If you want global vars you need to declare them as such so they can be updated.